# Which one should I use? over / on?

Tags: grammar

Which one should be correct fit for here?

> Tilted house on/ over silt

I think its "on", but need to be sure.

Comment: You've not even provided a full sentence, so it's hard to say for sure. Not only that, it's often hard to "be sure" when it comes to prepositions because many of them can overlap in meaning – to the point where more than one could be used and the sentence will still be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context is everything! All you've done is provide four words, which is not nearly enough information to help you figure out which preposition would be best to use.

For example, someone could build a house **on** silt, so it tilted:

[image]

or, someone could build a house **over** silt, and it might tilt, too:

[image]

My pictures show the way I would differentiate between the two phrases. However, the prepositions are flexible enough in meaning so that you could still use *over* in the top picture, and *on* in the bottom picture, and I don't think I'd argue that those sentences would be "incorrect."

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/over_1) defines **over** as:

> in a higher position above someone or something, without touching them

(thus, the bottom house is *over* silt). However, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over) defines *over* as:

> directly above; on the top of

so the first house is *over* silt as well.

These meanings aren't contradictory – they each simply list one (of many) possible meanings of a very multifaceted word. It's worth noting that Collins lists more than 10 defintions for *over*, and Macmillan lists around two dozen.